# JQuery Ajax Call Appending a Comma to Parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp

I have written a JQuery Ajax Call like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>CISCO Router Console</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            $(document).ready(function() {
                
                $('#verify_success').hide();
                $('#verify_fail').hide();
                $('#command_header').hide();
                $('#command_text').hide();
                $('#command_area').hide();
        
                $('#ip_submit').click(function (e) {
                
                    var ip = $('#ip_text').val();
                    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
                    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");                    
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/verifyRouterIP",
                        data: jQuery.param({ "routerIP": ip}),
                        beforeSend: function(request) {
                            request.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                        },
                        dataType: "text/plain",
                        contentType: "text/plain",
                        success: function() {      
                            $('#verify_success').show();
                            $('#command_header').show(20);
                            $('#command_text').show(30);
                            $('#command_area').show(40);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            
        </script>
        
        <form id="formSubmit" action="/verifyRouterIP" method="POST">
            <div id="heading" align="left" style="font-family: Verdana; color: blue; font-size: 20px">Welcome ${name}!! to CISCO Console</div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span id="ip_header" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: black; font-size: 14px">Router IP:  </span>
            <input id="ip_text" type="text" name="routerIP" style="text-align: left; background-color:gray; font-family: Verdana; color: black; font-size: 14px" size="40" name="routerIP">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input id="ip_submit" type="submit" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: black; font-size: 14px" value="Verify IP">
            <br>
            <br>
            <span id="verify_success" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: black; font-size: 14px">Router Verification Unsuccessful!</span>
            <br>
            <span id="verify_fail" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: red; font-size: 14px">Router Verification Successful!</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span id="command_header" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: black; col font-size: 14px">Enter an IOS Command:  </span>
            <br>
            <input id="command_text" type="text" style="text-align: left; font-family: Verdana; color: black; font-size: 12px" size="120" name="routerIP">
            <br>
            <br>
            <textarea id="command_area" cols="150" rows="50"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Controller Method is like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyRouterIP", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verifyRouterIP(@RequestParam(required = true) String routerIP, ModelMap modelMap) {

        boolean doesExist = deviceDetailsService.getDeviceDetailsByIPAddress(routerIP);

        if (doesExist) {

            modelMap.put("routerExists", true);

            return "redirect:/greeting";

        } else {

            modelMap.put("routerExists", false);

            return "redirect:/greeting";
        }
    }
```

When I use WebDeveloper on the browser I see that the IP is coming out fine:

[image: WebDeveloper]

But when I check Eclipse debugger, I see there is a `,` appended at the end.

[image: Eclipse]

That comma is something I don't need. Can you please tell me how to get rid of it. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: You don't need to use `jQuery.param()` here, although I'm unable to replicate your issue. If the `val()` doesn't return a comma in the value, `param()` won't add one: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/67pvjbky/. Possibly an issue with your server side model binder, or routing?

Comment: This happens when you have multiple form fields that have the same name. A common cause for this is to have hidden inputs and text inputs with the same name. The first time the page posts, the hidden inputs will be empty so, no commas. The second (and subsiquent) time the page posts, the hidden inputs will have values, so you get commas.

Comment: @Alien I can confirm that `ip_text` is the only unique `id` that I have in the JSP. I have updated the main question with the full JSP. I am going back to JSP/JQuery after almost a decade, but this one has got be stuffed!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have uploaded the full JSP, see if that sheds some light on it.

Comment: You have name= "routerIp" for multiple input fields. Just make them distinct and see.

Comment: Reply fast, will try to fix it today.

Comment: @Alien Removing the `routerIP` fixed the issue. I never the `name` attribute would cause such an issue, especially when I was fetching everything with the `id`. But could you please make it the answer. I will select it. But super thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP file has multiple input fields with same names and that's why the values are picked for all of them.

As name will be mapped to request parameter in Java.